# Compare NSdata carrying dictionary object to a String

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, xcode4.3

I want to figure out how to do this

```
NSData *xxx = [xxx objectForKey:@"xxx"];
if (xxx == @"xxx")
//do somthing
```

Comment: `if ([xxx objectForKey:@"xxx"] isEqualTostring =@"xxx"
 )`

Comment: May I ask why you cast the result to `NSData *` though you expect a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use introspection to determine whether or not an object is the same data type as another, but you'll have to do it like this (note the type `id`);

```
id *obj = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];

if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    if ([obj isEqualToString:@"text"])
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you may just use `isEqual:` which allows to compare to any object, without having to test for the class first.

```
id obj = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
if ( [obj isEqual:@"text"] ) {
    //...
}
```